# How to set system variable on mac? Since i could not get the system variable by using python 3 os.getenv or os.environ

Tags: python, macos

I am pretty sure i've set the system variable as following:

```
echo 'export TEST=/path/test' >> .bash_profile
echo 'export TEST=/path/test' >> .zshrc
```

And it is possible to get the variable from terminal just like:

```
echo $TEST
#the '/path/test' was print out
```

But i could not get it from python 3, as following:

```
TEST = os.getenv('TEST')
```

or

```
TEST = os.environ['TEST']
```

Does anyone know why? Any clue would be appreciated

Comment: Is Python being run from your shell or by some other mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused by the distinction between *environment* variables and (as you put it) *system* variables. When you run

```
echo 'export TEST=/path/test' >> .bash_profile
echo 'export TEST=/path/test' >> .zshrc
```

What you are doing is setting *environment* variables. What happens is that when you start a shell subsystem, the OS calls certain startup files to set variables for your environment. If you are in a Bash shell, it will call .profile, .bash_profile, etc. When you get your shell, any variables you set in your startup scripts are set for your environment. So for instance:

```
pswaminathan ~ $ export TEST=/path/test
pswaminathan ~ $ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Mar 24 2014, 00:31:02)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv('TEST')
'/path/test'
```

But `$TEST` here is not set up at the system level. It is set up at the *environment* level. It relies on being set; in your case, by the .zshrc or .bash_profile file. If you are running a script by cron, for example, you can set your environment varaibles in the crontab. Or you can set your envvars in a shell script you're using to run these. So how are you running this file, where you're not getting the right environment variables?

Also good reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable

Comment: This is probably the OP's issue at hand but as he/she has not state how they are running Python who knows ;)

Comment: Hi, my python script is actually a sublime text 3 plugin, while sublime lanuched, the script get running.

Comment: So what environment variables do you need? Can you set them from within the plugin? `os.environ['TEST'] = '/path/test'` will set one. Can you set them from preferences? As it is a different environment from your shell, it's not calling the shell's startup files.

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot set them within plugin. I have to read this variable since i will use them in sublime.